# Function of a random variable definition

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

Here is a page from Casella Berger, here g(X) is a function of a random variable X, and $\chi$ is the sample space on which X is defined, then it is written that g defines a mapping from $\chi$ to a new sample space $\gamma$. But my understanding was that g is function of real numbers.